# MYSQL where on sum(tabl1.column_name) < tabl2.other_column

Tags: mysql

I have two tables products and sold_products

```
products -> id|name|quantity|price
sold_products -> id|product_id|quantity
```

what i need is to calculate the sum of quantity from sold_products and check the sum is greater than quantity from products table. something like below;

```
select p.* from products as p and sold_products as sp where p.quantity > sum(sp.quantity)
```

thanks in advance;

Answer (score 1):

you can make this by `join` 2 tables and use `having` with `group by`:

```
select p.quantity, sum(sp.quantity) 
from products as p 
inner join sold_products as sp
on p.id = sp.product_id
group by p.id
having p.quantity < sum(sp.quantity)
```

Answer (score 0):

`Group BY` with `HAVING` will work.

```
SELECT p.*
FROM products AS p, sold_products AS sp
WHERE p.id = sp.product_id
GROUP BY p.id 
HAVING sum(sp.quantity) > p.quantity
```

Answer (score 0):

it also working

```
select p.id,p.quantity, sum(sp.quantity)  from products1 as p  inner
join sold_products as sp on p.id = sp.product_id group by p.id
having sum(p.quantity) < sum(sp.quantity)
```

but @ Gouda Elalfy plz tell me how group by answering this